# How to Show different tables based on different dropdown values in .cshtml?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have an index.cshtml and it contains a drop down.
When we select a value from the dropdown, it should show data for the corresponding table in database (all of the tables have different columns). How can I accomplish this task ?

I am fairly new to C# and hence confused with how to show different views for different tables.

Comment: Can you share code examples for clear understanding, fixing etc.

Comment: It is a simple drop down and a table on page. And when I select a value from the drop down it will fetch data from controller and update the table contents.
How can I achieve this ? Because if I refresh the page then drop down value gets lost and it again shows the previous data in table

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a form,when click search button,data of dropdown will be passed to action,and action try to return a list according to the data of dropdown:

Index View:

```
<form method="post">
    Type:<select name="type">
         ...
         </select>
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
<table>
...
</table>
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult Index(string type="")
{
    //return a list according to the type
}
```